# Ball not rolling in Unity Roll A Ball tutorial

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am doing the roll a ball tutorial but the ball won't roll. I even copied the code from the website and it still didn't work. This is the code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 0;

    private Rigidbody rb;

    private float movementX;
    private float movementY;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    private void OnMove(InputValue movementValue)
    {
        Vector2 movementVector = movementValue.Get<Vector2>();

        movementX = movementVector.x;
        movementY = movementVector.y;
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        Vector3 movement = new Vector3(movementX, 0.0f, movementY);

        rb.AddForce(movement * speed);
    }

}
```

Can anyone help me figure out the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my first ever answer, so sorry if it isn't good, but here we go

You never call the OnMove function, so movementX and movementY will always be undefined, as it is not a built in function that I'm aware of. Call it before getting your movement vector, and you should be set! Cheers

Comment: wait so what you are saying is like to call on move in the fixed update? or somewhere else?